# Get data from table as per condition with different entity

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have table of employees details where I am maintaining two languages like english and arabic. Now when employee is register then he will fill profile in english and arabic. So I want count those employees who has fill his details in both languages.

Table : EmployeeDetails

```
UserID | FirstName | LastName | LanguageId
1          temp         user       1
1          temp1        user1      2
2          temp         user       1
2          NULL         NULL       2
```

So here I want count of those employees who has details in both languages. So it should be 1.

I have try with this query like :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EmployeeDetails
WHERE FirstName IS NOT NULL AND LastName IS NOT NULL
```

But it's giving me wrong result. So how can I get my expectation result ?

Comment: Why is the result "wrong". Is the result not `3`? What result are you getting instead?

Comment: How can a UserID have different names?

Comment: @Larnu yes, it is giving me 3 records of 2 user. So count is 2 but it should be 1 because I want count of those users who have fill profile in language 1 and language 2(in both languages).

Comment: But there *are* 3 users in that table that don't have names of `NULL`, @jignesh . The design of your database is wrong here. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do what you want using aggregation and `having`:

```
select ed.userid
from employeedetails ed
where ed.languageid in (1, 2)
group by ed.userid
having count(*) = 2;  - number of languages
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, it seems like the problem is your design, not the data. You should have 3 tables, not 2 here. One for the users, another for the languages, and then a final one for the languages the user has. Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Users (UserID int NOT NULL,
                        FirstName varchar(50),
                        LastName varchar(50));

ALTER TABLE dbo.Users ADD CONSTRAINT PK_UserID PRIMARY KEY (UserID);
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Languages (LanguageID int NOT NULL,
                            LanguageName varchar(50))

ALTER TABLE dbo.Languages ADD CONSTRAINT PK_LanguageID PRIMARY KEY (LanguageID);
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.UserLanguages (UserID int NOT NULL,
                                LanguageID int NOT NULL);

ALTER TABLE dbo.UserLanguages ADD CONSTRAINT PK_UserLanguage PRIMARY KEY (UserID,LanguageID);

ALTER TABLE dbo.UserLanguages ADD CONSTRAINT FK_UserID FOREIGN KEY (UserID) REFERENCES dbo.Users(UserID);
ALTER TABLE dbo.UserLanguages ADD CONSTRAINT FK_LanguageID FOREIGN KEY (LanguageID) REFERENCES dbo.Languages(LanguageID);

GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Users (UserID,
                       FirstName,
                       LastName)
VALUES (1,'temp','user'),
       (2,'test','login');
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Languages (LanguageID,
                           LanguageName)
VALUES(1,'English'),
      (2,'Arabic');

GO

INSERT INTO dbo.UserLanguages (UserID,
                               LanguageID)
VALUES(1,1),
      (1,2),
      (2,1),
      (2,2);

GO

SELECT COUNT(*) --2, as there are 2 users
FROM dbo.Users;

SELECT COUNT(*) --Also 2, as both users are learning English
FROM dbo.Users U
     JOIN dbo.UserLanguages UL ON U.UserID = UL.UserID
     JOIN dbo.Languages L ON UL.LanguageID = L.LanguageID
WHERE L.LanguageName = 'English';

SELECT COUNT(*) --4, as there are 2 users, learning 2 languages each (2 * 2 = 4)
FROM dbo.Users U
     JOIN dbo.UserLanguages UL ON U.UserID = UL.UserID
     JOIN dbo.Languages L ON UL.LanguageID = L.LanguageID;
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.UserLanguages
DROP TABLE dbo.Users;
DROP TABLE dbo.Languages
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need a `distinct count()`

```
Select count(distinct userid) from EmployeeDetails
where FirstName is not null and LastName is not null
```